# module not found - typescript cli

Tags: typescript, command-line-interface

this is my project : https://github.com/CrunchyArtie/pile-de-la-honte-cli

when use it locally (`npm run dev` or `npm i -g .`) it's working but when I use the archive builded by `npm pack` or install it after publishing, it's not working.

the error :

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:796
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module './models/questions/home.question'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\lundi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pile-de-la-honte\dist\index.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:793:17)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:686:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:848:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\lundi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pile-de-la-honte\dist\index.js:10:25)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:955:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:991:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:811:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:14)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1043:10) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'C:\\Users\\lundi\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\pile-de-la-honte\\dist\\index.js'
  ]
}
```

And the dist folder only container `index.js`.

I try to add to the `package.json` :

```
main: "dist/index.js",
bin: "dist/index.js"
```

and this tsconfig :

```
"extends": "@tsconfig/recommended/tsconfig.json",
"include": [
    "src/**/*"
],
"exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
],
"compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "dist",
    "lib": [
        "es6",
        "es2015",
        "dom",
        "es2019",
        "es2017",
        "es7"
    ],
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "rootDir": "src",
    "strict": true,
    "types": ["node"],
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
        "./*": [
            "dist/*"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the parent folder of `./models/questions/home.question` in `C:/Users/lundi/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/pile-de-la-honte/dist`?

Comment: at the first try no, but I had the lines ` "paths": {"./*": ["dist/*"]}` in the tsconfig file. Now there is the home.question file in `C:/Users/lundi/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/pile-de-la-honte/dist/src`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The problem :** In the `.gitignore` there is the `dist` folder.

**The solution :**

1. Duplicate the `.gitignore`,
2. Rename this new file to `.npmignore`,
3. Open `.npmignore` and remove the line about `dist` folder.

**Why :** Npm will pack the entire project expect :

- nothing if there are no `.gitignore` or `.npmignore`,
- the content listed in the `.npmignore` if this file exist.
- the content listed in the `.gitignore` if this file exist but not the `.npmignore`.